# Abnormal Emission Behaviour in Blender

Tags: animation, eevee-render-engine, lighting, glass, emission

I have been making a glass bottle animation in which the bottle is tilted sideway and supposed to rotate about the Z-axis. The liquid inside the bottle is luminous because I want to achieve a magical vibe. However, after I am done with the animation I realized that there is always an angle where the lighting of the liquid cannot pass through the bottle, which results in inconsistent lighting when the bottle is rotated.(as shown below)
[image]
[image]
I have done some simple troubleshooting and realized that after I disabled the glass bottle, the liquid itself behaves properly as I expected. I have tried to scale down the liquid body and shift it more towards the center part of the glass bottle but the same issue still persists. Now I am totally clueless on how to solve the issue. Below are the material settings of my glass bottle and the liquid body.
Glass Bottle Material:
[image]
[image]
Glowing Liquid Material:
[image]
Not sure whether the information provided is sufficient, but I would be glad if anyone can offer any clue on why there is such a problem and how I am supposed to resolve this. Thank you very much.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please share your blend file https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: Try lowering the IOR of the glass down to 1.25 or so. It might make the glass a bit less realistic, but it should allow more emission to pass through.